# How to pass sender through event handler

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, events, xaml

I'm using the http://wpfmdi.codeplex.com/ library to handle MDI in my WPF application.

I've got a Canvas which contains a child container, which in turn contains a number of small windows.  I would like to perform an action when one of the small windows is closed, so I tried to do the following:

```
MdiChild child = new MdiChild();
child.Closing += new RoutedEventHandler(DatabaseTableWindow_Closing); 

private void DatabaseTableWindow_Closing(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            object s = e.Source;
        }
```

While the method is successfully entered when a window is closed, `e.Source` is null.  I've also checked the `sender` and that is null too.  All I want is a way to find out which window fired the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `sender` is `null`, then it sounds like an oversight/bug in the MDI framework you are using. Since you have the source, you can fix it: locate the place(s) where the `Closing` event is raised, and add `this` as the sender. That should give you a reference to the `MdiChild` when you are handling the event.

Comment: This is what I've found. Should I change this? 

public static readonly RoutedEvent ClosingEvent =
   EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent("Closing", RoutingStrategy.Bubble, typeof(ClosingEventArgs), typeof(MdiChild));

Comment: @DotNET There should be someplace where the "Closing" `RoutedEvent` is raised and the `RoutedEventArgs` created. This would be the place to set the source.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably use LINQ to circumvent the issue:

```
child.Closing += (o,e) => { DatabaseTableWindow_Closing(this, e); };
```

**Edit**: Actually in this case you should not use "this", but "child" (which would point to your MdiChild):

```
MdiChild child = new MdiChild();
child.Closing += (o,e) => { DatabaseTableWindow_Closing(child, e); };
```

Comment: I've tried it and it seems to work - however if it causes a memory leak is there another approach that can be taken @Sisyphe ?

Comment: I think Jay is right, the MDI framework source code should be fixed and give you a proper sender.

Comment: Take a look at this link : http://alookonthecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/lambda-expressions-anonymous-classes.html . You can still create a question here, I'll answer it if you have issues understanding the problem here.

Comment: @Sisyphe I am getting a different opinion from these memory leak in this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989781/lambda-and-memory-leaks-looking-for-alternative-approaches/12989895#12989895

Comment: @Sisyphe: Why does this code produce a memory leak? Where? Read the blog post you mentioned and the comments carefully. If you feel better, use a WeakReference to pass "this" into the lambda expression: `MdiChild child = new MdiChild();` then `var weakRef = new WeakReference(child);` and then `child.Closing += (o,e) => { DatabaseTableWindow_Closing(weakRef.Target, e); };`.

Comment: The issue is caused by the inplicit use of this (call to DatabaseTableWindow_Closing) and the use of child as parameter. If you look into the IL, there will be a class generated that will have a strong reference to this. Using a WeakReference indeed solves the issue.

Comment: However, I may be wrong, I'll still make a quick example with a similar code and get memory snapshot to explicitely check.

Comment: @Sisyphe: Why is a strong reference in the generated class a problem? The class is finalized at some point, and then the strong reference is also released.

Comment: @CarstenSchütte Yeah, but in this case, when will the generated class be finalized exactly ?

Comment: @Sisyphe: The generated class is referenced by the event. So it will be released when the event is released, and the event is released when the owner form is released.

Comment: Thanks guys. I am going to trust Carsten and .NET's "supposed" integrity for now, until someone can prove that you can effectively create memory leaks using Linq and local variables. I'm pretty sure that if Microsoft allows this functionality, it's because they made it so it works. Unfortunately i'm not good enough to research this on my own. Thanks for the time, guys.